# "My job is not to worry about those people" — what does "not" refer to?

Tags: meaning, negation, ambiguity

In the famous leaked [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sn6W5WQ5ak), Mitt Romney says

> My job is not to worry about those people

An equivalent sentence probably is

> It is not my job to worry about those people

Some media in my home country have translated it to something roughly like

> My job is: not to worry about those people

The difference is that the *not* can be assigned to "my job is" or either to "to worry about those people. I actually do not know how this difference can be demonstrated by two proper English sentences, so I hope you get the idea.

Question: Can these different shades of meanings be rendered in English just by word order or grammatical particles? Is there any ambiguity in Mitt Romney's statement?

Comment: When arranging words in negative or other constructions, often a compromise has to be reached between total unambiguousness and sounding ridiculous. 'My job is not to worry about these people' admittedly sounds like Romney is claiming that that is the sum total of what his job entails (as the media translation wrongly interprets it), but it is understood to mean the same as your own fine suggestion. It sounds a little more formal, less defensive, the way Romney puts it.

Comment: That is *pragmatics* domain. *My job is not* = *It is not my job* per context;  = *It is my job(|) not (to)* is counter pragmatic. Grammar's job is not to rule usage and construction (how something is construed). Romney said what he meant; the media punned as it is its job.

Comment: And politicians are by definition pragmatists.

Comment: Romney put it badly. Your second quote is correct and much less ambiguous, Martin

Comment: Your second sentence contains truth, Elendil, but, as I say above, Romney doesn't sound as dismissive by using the variant he chooses. It depends on how you define 'put it badly'.

Comment: This kind of sloppy language is typical of all native speakers. If he said it orally, he can be forgiven for speaking the way all native speakers speak: as if everyone can read their mind & groks pragmatics (which has zilch to do with their _any end I seek justifies any means I use_ pragmatism). If he actually wrote it down, then he's just perverse, as are all purveyors of ambiguity (that's what political pragmatism's really about: saying one thing but meaning another). Only Adlai E. Stevenson II was eloquent egghead enough to know the difference. Romney's dog always got 47% of his tongue.

Comment: So I infer that the second rephrasement is actually the 'correct' one, with regards to strict grammar rules. I am surprised!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two meanings can be rendered in English just by using different word order.

> 1. It is not my job to worry about those people.
> 2. It is my job to not worry about those people.

However, the second one is, of course, a very unlikely interpretation of Romney's original quote. Nobody's job, not even that of a politician, consists entirely of not worrying about just one thing and doing nothing else at all. (For starters, for every human in every profession there are always *several* things they don't worry about.)

Comment: The second one is how I read it. *Job* as "task" not "An economic role for which a person is paid": http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/job#Noun.

Comment: *‘Forward, the Light Brigade!’ /
Was there a man dismay’d? /
Not tho’ the soldier knew /
Some one had blunder’d: /
Theirs not to make reply, /
Theirs not to reason why, / 
Theirs but to do & die, /
Into the valley of Death /
Rode the six hundred.*

Answer (score -2):

The statement:

> My job is not to worry about those people

means

> I have an active responsibility to be indifferent to these people

whereas:

> It is not my job to worry about those people

means

> I have no responsibility to have sympathy for these people

The translation is correct.

Comment: Not true.  The sentence is technically ambiguous as given but would ordinarily be parsed as "my job is not (x)" instead of "my job is (not x)".